# Sharepoint Code to break inheritance and add new permissions at custom list level

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, custom-list, csom, roles

I have a site collection with permissions set up as: EVERYONE READ
I have a custom list. Here, I want to add permissions as EVERYONE CONTRIBUTE.
I want to remove the Everyone Read Access Permssions but retain all other permissions like site members, owners, visitors etc to remain the same as that of site collection.

I am using this code to change the permssions(powershell and CSOM) :

```
$myList= $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(“Emp List”)
$myList.breakRoleInheritance($true, $false)
$everyone = $context.Web.EnsureUser("EveryOne") 
$everyoneRoleDef=$context.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Contribute")
$context.Load($everyoneRoleDef)
$roledefbingding_EveryOne=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection $context
$context.Load($roledefbingding_EveryOne)
$roledefbingding_EveryOne.Add($everyoneRoleDef)
$context.Load($myList.RoleAssignments.Add($everyone, $roledefbingding_EveryOne))
$myList.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

The above code is perfectly working.

But it removes all other permissions for the list like: visitors, owners etc. - This is not expected. May be it happens because of the below line of code:

```
 $myList.breakRoleInheritance($true, $false)
```

I tried  `$myList.breakRoleInheritance($false, $true)`
But this will add permission as : EVERYONE READ,CONTRIBUTE - This is not expected.

This code adds "EVERYONE" as Contributors - This is expected.

DO I need to remove existing role ? If so please help me how to achieve this?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try just deleting the Read role definition after adding the Contribute definition as follows:

```
$myList= $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(“Emp List”);
$myList.breakRoleInheritance($true, $false);
$everyone = $context.Web.EnsureUser("EveryOne");
$everyoneRoleDef=$context.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Contribute");
$everyoneReadRoleDef=$context.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Read");
$context.Load($everyoneRoleDef);
$roledefbingding_EveryOne=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection $context;
$context.Load($roledefbingding_EveryOne);
$roledefbingding_EveryOne.Add($everyoneRoleDef);
$context.Load($myList.RoleAssignments.Add($everyone, $roledefbingding_EveryOne));
$context.Load($myList.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal($everyoneReadRoleDef).DeleteObject();
$myList.Update();
$context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your right breakRoleInheritance will break everything. Test it out in front end UI.

breakRoleInheritance : List will not inherit anything from sitecollection.
You may need to add the remaining Groups in powershell again.

Comment: This answer doesn't add any value because it simply states the obvious that was already noted (more elaborately) in the question itself.